# Is the exclamation "like seriously" proper?

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage

Often times I've heard some people expressing their surprise state with 'like serious'. Is it appropriate?

> Roy: My dad bought me a Ford Expedition for my lectures.
>   Smith: Like seriously?

Comment: Yes. Its proper. You can say it just that way to express the feeling like you don't believe it.

Comment: You can also just say "seriously" (with question intonation). I don't believe the "like" makes any difference.

Comment: @hunter - Unless it's, like, overused. In that case, like, the word "like" only makes a _little_ difference, in that it can, like, make you sound, like, less intelligent.

Comment: I quite enjoyed everyone's contribution on this. I do not fancy its use  anyway. I'd rather prefer 'seriously'? That  makes it simple and  logical.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very modern colloquial form of English, that whilst understandable, is very informal, and which might be out of place, for instance, in an interview or at a formal occasion.

Additionally other than in verbatim transcription, this isn't something I'd write or really expect to see written, except perhaps in a magazine opinion column, internet forum, instant messenger/text message or other extremely informal piece of writing.

That said, it is commonly spoken by many English speakers, and would be widely understood as expressing surprise and/or incredulity at a statement; the modern form of "Are you being serious?".

Comment: It's certainly informal, but I think you overstate that a bit. I don't think anyone would find it jarring to see such a statement in writing of an everyday level of formality. I wouldn't expect to see it in a scholarly paper. Like, "It has traditionally been believed that the Sun emits neutrionos. Seriously, guys? Our team conducted a series of experiments ..." No, not likely. But, "Senator Jones accused Senator Brown of being a racist. Seriously? Senator Jones seems to accuse everyone who disagrees with him of being a racist ..." I wouldn't find that out of place at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is, in some applications, improper. For instance, when a person makes an error in opinion, the speaker gives the addressed person a feeling of being ridiculously stupid.